# Remove query string in Nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to remove query strings using proxy_pass in Nginx?
For example i call my nginx on:

```
http://nginxproxy.com/api/v1/logout?session=123
```

And would like to proxy this to:

```
http://example.com/api/sessions/?_action=logout
```

Without the query string "session=123".

Currently my setup just adds any query string i pass to the proxy_pass URL.

```
location /api/v2/logout {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Session $arg_token;
        proxy_pass http://example.com/api/sessions/?_action=logout;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking to remove any query string specified on `/api/v2/logout`, adding `set $args "";` should work:

```
location /api/v2/logout {
    set $args "";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Session $arg_token;
    proxy_pass http://example.com/api/sessions/?_action=logout;
}
```

Comment: This did nothing for me with nginx 1.20.1 -- the answer from @Thierry worked though

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do it with a rewrite rule like:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?;
```